# Why do i need to specifically check for false using react and javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to render a div element only if condition1 or condition2 is true.

below is my code.

```
const Parent = () => {
    const {notify} = useNotification();
    return (
        <SomeComponent 
            notify ({
                actions: showInfo(item),
            });
        />
    );
}

const showInfo = (item) => {
    return (
        <>
            {condition === 'value1' || condition === 'value2' ?
                <div>header</div>
                : undefined
            }
        </>
    );
}

const useNotifications = () => {
    const [activeNotifications, setActiveNotifications] = React.useContext(NotificationContext);
    const notify = React.useCallback(
        (notifications: Notification | Notification[]) => {
            setActiveNotifications(activeNotifications => [
                 ...activeNotifications,
            ]);
        }
        [setActiveNotifications]
    );
    return notify;
}


const Notification: React.FC<Props> = ({
    description,actions}) => {
        console.log('actions',actions) //here actions is printed false
        return (
            {(description || actions) && ( //why doesnt this condition work
                <Body>//this is displayed even if actions is false
                    {actions && <div> {actions} </div>}
                </Body>
            }
        );
     }
 })
```

in the above code the Body div is displayed even though actions is false as seen from console log statement.

if i change the condition to

```
{(description || actions === true) &&
     <Body>//this is not displayed
         {actions && <div>{actions}</div>}
     </Body>
}
```

could someone help me understand why i have to explicitly check if {actions === true} and why {actions} doesnt work.
thanks.

```
EDIT: the type for the action is set like below

export type NotificationProps = {
  actions?: React.ReactNode;
}
```

Comment: What type is  the `actions` variable? Is it a boolean or is it maybe a string?

Comment: It looks like your `actions` is a React component, so it cannot be neither `true` nor `false`, you need to find a better way to determine when to show `Body`, if you keep it as `actions === true` it will never render

Comment: What is your requirement? Do you need to display the Body if both description is not null and actions is true?

Comment: actions currently is an object or boolean.  true when i kept actions === true it dint render. so  i kept the condition to actions !== false and it works. seems like in the code actions seems to be of two values either React component or false as i am passing either reactcomponent or undefined as in showInfo method. not sure how it is becoming false.

Comment: requirement is to display Body if actions has some value which is React component . if not dont show

Comment: @Nadia Chibrikova: what you said is correct. how should i determine the condition to display Body component? thanks

Comment: the type for actions seems to be actions? : React.ReactNode

Comment: check out maybe instead of boolean true or false you have strings 'true' or 'false'

Comment: your comment "//this is displayed even if actions is false"  this could be displayed only if description OR actions is truthy value. In your case description could be true, object, string, etc

Comment: *"in the above code the Body div is displayed even though actions is false as seen from console log statement."* Have you checked the contents of `description`? Because `<Body>...</Body>` is shown if either `description` or `actions` is truthy. So even though `actions` is `false`, if `description` is truthy the body will still render.

Comment: description is undefined and actions is false.

Comment: @stackuser are you sure that it is undefined or false and not strings? could you do console.log(typeof description,typeof action)

Comment: description is undefined and actions is object

Comment: @stackuser now everything is logic. Object is always truthy value ( undefined || {} ) will be true because {} is truthy. And {}=== true will be false. In your case, you should check if actions object contains any values and only then do render

Comment: thanks could you add an answer.